# Email with embedded images showing as "Preview Document" in Outlook 2010 & 2016

Tags: c#, html-email

We are currently sending a relatively simple email in C# via Amazon SES.  For almost all clients the email looks correctly but Outlook is not showing the email but showing it as an attachment.

Email building code:

```
 LinkedResource logoResource = null;
 //Attach Logo 
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailMessage.Logo))
 {
     messageHtml = messageHtml.Replace("{{Logo}}", emailMessage.Logo);
     var imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(emailMessage.Logo.Split(Convert.ToChar(","))[1]);

     logoResource = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(imageData))
     {
         ContentId = "logo",
         ContentType = new ContentType("image/png"),
         TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64
     };
 }
 var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(messageHtml, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logoResource);

var message = new MailMessage {
   IsBodyHtml = false,
   Subject = emailMessage.Subject,
   Body = string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailMessage.MessageText) ? emailMessage.Message : emailMessage.MessageText,
   From = new MailAddress(emailMessage.From)
 };

message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Template:

```
<tr style="margin-bottom:15px;/*logostyle*/">
    <td width="600" class="mobile" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;  padding: 10px;" align="center">
    <img src="cid:logo"  style="width: 350px" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

Let me know if there is anything else that interest you.

[image: outlook]

Comment: hotmail.com and outlook like to change the src of the images from http to https. Maybe it changes the src in your case too. Then outlook doesn't know where to display the image, so it displays it as an attachment

Comment: This is an inline image?  So we are not referencing a server.

Comment: CreateAlternateViewFromString stopped working correctly for me also.  What I had to do was for SES was convert the message to a raw memory stream and send it that way. You can use the SES SendRawEmail call. I can send a code snippet.

Comment: @Nix I know.. But I would check if the src is correct in the source code of the email

Comment: It shows up fine in other browsers (the image) @ManosPasgiannis

Comment: Does setting IsBodyHtml = true help?  Since you are using a HTML view and template.

Answer (score 1):

I think Outlook does not have an alternate view, that's why it does not work for it.

Small Snippet to send the mail once you create your mail message object.

```
RawMessage rawMessage;

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(gMessage))
{
    rawMessage = new RawMessage(memoryStream);
}

SendRawEmailRequest request = new SendRawEmailRequest();

request.RawMessage = rawMessage;
request.Destinations.Add(MessageToSend.ToRecipient.Trim().ToLower());
request.Source = MessageToSend.SenderEmail;

var ses = new Amazon.SimpleEmail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(UserName, sMailPassword, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

SendRawEmailResponse response = ses.SendRawEmail(request);
```

Here is the ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream that came from an [Amazon Support forum](https://goo.gl/TrCqBu) .

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the mail message to memory stream. https://goo.gl/TrCqBu
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message.</param>
/// <returns>MemoryStream.</returns>
public static MemoryStream ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(MailMessage message)
{
    Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
    Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
    MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();
    ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
    object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { fileStream });
    MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    if (sendMethod.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);
    else
        sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);

    MethodInfo closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new object[] { }, null);
    return fileStream;
}
```